# Get my country from my current location google map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google map v2 in my android app to get my location and it works well. Now I want to get my country meaning that if I'm in Cairo or Alexandria, the code tells me that I'm in Egypt. And if I'm in New York or Washington, the code tells me that I'm in USA.

How can I do this by code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Google Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

Sending a LatLng, you get a list of possible addresses. One of them is the country.

Example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

Comment: I'm already sending LatLng and I get my location well, but I want to get my country in toast for example. what is the code to get it?

Comment: @Eman87 `Toast.makeText(context, "Your country is: " + country, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: I feel that you didn't got my mean, I know the code of toast itself, but how to get the value of "country" that you wrote in the code of toast?

Comment: You can get the country value by using the reverse geocoding api mentioned above. Country is one of the [address component](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) type that will be returned by a reverse geocoding request